# Ler arquivo .xls

Tags: python, xls

Estou com um problema ao ler um arquivo .xls usando Python com Flask.

Meu código:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename=settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/xls/arquivo.xls', read_only=True)
    ws = wb['Tab 1']

    for row in ws.get_squared_range(min_col=2,max_col=34, min_row=2, max_row=61):
        for cell in row:
            print(cell.value)
```

O erro obtido é:

> NameError: name 'settings' is not defined

Comment: eu tentei fazer uma edição para tentar deixar mais legível. Poderia verificar se eu não acrescentei algum nível acidental de identação no código original?

Comment: Falou o import desse settings não? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844953/how-to-access-media-root-in-py-file. O link ´´e sobre o Django mas a ideia é a mesma.